# Android 11 bug: App crash with java.lang.SecurityException: uid xxxxx cannot explicitly add accounts of type: package.name

Tags: java, android, kotlin

EDIT:
I have an error that crash my application, `java.lang.SecurityException: uid xxxxx cannot explicitly add accounts of type: package.name` , I know there are other similar posts here, but I cannot find a solution.

I think the following happens, when a user wants to login to the application, there are cases where the application crashes. when does it crash? when calling the addAccountExplicitly method. I checked the Android permissions and the authentication file which are the most common causes, and tried to log in with both of my apps at the same time to try to replicate the crash, but was unsuccessful.

The problem occurs in the first seconds of use, when I am trying to add an account, the line where it crash is the following
`if (accountManager.addAccountExplicitly (account, null, null))`
where accountManager and account are

```
val account = account
val accountManager = context.getSystemService (Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE) as AccountManager
```

I have no idea why this happens, and why it does it only to some users.

---

I wanted to know if having two different signature packages could lead to the problem, for example I have the same application with package name package.name1 and package.name2, package.name1 is different from package.name2 just for GUI. Can someone help me please? It is one of my first posts on stackoverflow, sorry if I made a mistake.

It is not a recurring bug but it appears every week at least once

---

EDIT:
I have two flavors for each app.

Authenticator 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accountType="package.name1"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:smallIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="App1" />
```

Authenticator 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accountType="package.name2"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:smallIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="App2" />
```

Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>
```

EDIT: Well, I found something interesting, the application has 11 crashes in 90 days, and all cases were on Android 11, was there any change in Android 11 that may affect the add AccountExplicit method?

Comment: You said "I have an error that blocks my application" but didn't show in the question. Please include it, thats the starting point.

Comment: yes that was my fault, I meant crash, english is not my mother tongue. what should I add? the stack trace?

Comment: Include what you assuming is an error. Stack trace and your source code are additional info.

Comment: OK thanks, I made the changes, I hope they are useful to you

Comment: You still haven't included the error. You have include the line where it is throwing the error.

Comment: Read this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: well, I tried to improve the post, if it's still not right don't worry, I'll try something else, anyway thank you very much, I learned a lot